# Product.find(query).distinct('field'). Как подсчитать количество уникальных полей?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Product.find(query)
    .distinct('brand')

С помощью такого запроса я получаю массив из всех уникальных значений с ключом brand.

А каким способом можно получить информацию о том сколько каждых уникальных значений есть в коллекции?

Допустим такая коллекция

```
  {brand: adidas},
  {brand: nike},
  {brand: NB},
  {brand: adidas},
  {brand: adidas},
```

И мне нужен не просто массив ['adidas', 'nike', 'NB']

а что то вроде этого:

```
   [{adidas: 3}, {nike: 1}, {NB: 1}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте аггрегации https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/aggregation/

```
Product.aggregate([
    {$group: {_id: "$brand", count: {$sum: 1}}
])
```

Получите массив вида:

```
[
  {_id: "adidas", count: 3},
  {_id: "nike", count: 1},
  {_id: "NB", count: 1}
]
```